# Android unit test: access manifest of test application

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I have an Android unit test on my Android library project that reads meta data (meta-data) from the manifest. I want to populate my test app's manifest with the test meta data.

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foo.bar">

  <application>
    <meta-data
        android:value="com.foo.bar.dbnames" android:resource="@array/dbnames"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

However, I've discovered that when I obtain the package manager in my test case implementation, it's accessing the manifest of my Android library project, not the test app.

Is there any way to force the test case run to point to the test app's manifest?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is extend `ApplicationTestCase<Application>` for your test case class.

You can call `getContext()` in your test cases and that will have the appropriate information in there.

```
PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(getContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Comment: that's not true. that context is the context of the app that's being tested, not the test application itself. i want the context of the test APK.